# Random reboots after GFX upgrade. Power issues?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, reboot

I upgraded my GFX from GeForce GTX 560 to GTX 770. The system booted fine, drivers were installed, but after a while it rebooted. Just before the reboot, I also noticed my second (mechanical) HDD was no longer being recognized.

This looks to me like I don't have enough power, so I dug into the specs:

- According to [EVGA](https://www.evga.com/products/specs/gpu.aspx?pn=fa93efc9-a44b-448c-bcea-aff0b5bd7aeb), I need 600W PSU with 42A on the +12V rail.
- According to [Chieftec](https://mobilespecs.net/power/Chieftec/Chieftec_CFT-650-14CS_650W.html), I have 4*18=72A on the +12V rail.

What seems to be the problem given the above? My guess is the PSU is broken and doesn't output enough power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely do have a power issue and will likely need a larger PSU:

---

**Ohm's Law: `V * A = W`**

- **V***oltage* **x** **A***mperage* **= W***attage*

---

- EVGA states a minimum of 42A on the 12V rail (504W) must be available
- Cheiftec PSU is a 650W max PSU, leaving only 146W for the MB and all components

  - Cheiftec displays the maximum current that can be on any of it's power circuits at one time, not that that current is available across all circuits all the time.
  - Total output power cannot exceed 650W across *all* circuits:

    - 1x **3.3V Max** *(30A)***: *99W***
    - 1x **5V Max** *(28A)***: *140W***
    - 4x **12V Max** *(18A/per)***: *216W****/per*
    - 1x **-12V Current** *(800mA)***: *9.6W***
    - 1x **5V Standby** *(3A)***: *15W***

Comment: After replacing the PSU the reboots are no more. Thanks for your helpful answer, from now on in addition to pure specs I'm going to take power balance into account.